# Moodle automatically certificate send

Tags: moodle

I'm configuring moodle certificate plugin and I have question. Is there any way to configure certificate plugin to send certificate automatically after passing an exam ?

And second Question:
Is there any way to send quiz result via email?

Thanks for answers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about configuring Moodle, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

There's a quiz_attempt_submitted event

```
/mod/quiz/db/events.php
```

Which sends an object with these properties

```
->component   = 'mod_quiz';
->attemptid   = // The id of the quiz attempt that was submitted.
->timefinish  = // The timestamp of when the attempt was submitted.
->timestamp   = // The timestamp of when the attempt was submitted.
->userid      = // The user id that the attempt belongs to.
->submitterid = // The user id of the user who sumitted the attempt.
->quizid      = // The quiz id of the quiz the attempt belongs to.
->cmid        = // The course_module id of the quiz the attempt belongs to.
->courseid    = // The course id of the course the quiz belongs to.
```

You could write a local plugin that responds to the submitted event and checks if they have passed the exam. If they have then send an email.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Events_API#Handling_an_event

Create /local/sendcertificate/db/events.php with something like

```
$handlers = array (
    'quiz_attempt_submitted' => array (
        'handlerfile'      => '/local/sendcertificate/lib.php',
        'handlerfunction'  => 'local_sendcertificate_quizsubmitted',
        'schedule'         => 'instant',
        'internal'         => 1,
    ),
);
```

Then in /local/sendcertificate/lib.php

```
function local_sendcertificate_quizsubmitted($quizattempt) {
     // Check if quizattempt is successful
     // Generate the certificate as a pdf
     // Email it to the user
}
```

You'll need to add a few more files for the local plugin

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins

Answer (score 0):

Neither 'mod_certificate' nor 'mod_simplecertificate' have an option of sending a certificate via email automatically (by 'passing an exam', I assume you mean that the 'user completes some sort of activity in Moodle').

You can configure the certificate to be emailed to teachers (or a specific list of other users) at the point where it is viewed by a student (and you can set up the certificate to only be viewable when a certain criteria is met).

The only way to do what you want is for a developer to add the feature via code.

The quiz module can be configured to automatically sends email when the quiz is submitted (to the teacher and/or the student who submitted it) and to send an email when a quiz is overdue. The only way you can send the results via email is to manually export them and then email them yourself.

Again, this is a feature that could be added by a developer, but which cannot be done without code changes.